# how to get the user role after logout in spring security and java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

*I want to get the user role after logout button is clicked.
if the role is **admin** i have to return /login.jsp in /logout

if the role is **user** i have to return /index.jsp in /logout*

Thanks in advance

**my controller.java:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/logout",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String logout(HttpServletRequest request,ModelMap model)
        {
    model.addAttribute("userForms",userService.getActiveUserList());
      model.addAttribute("Success",true);
      return "/login";
        }
```

**UserService.java**

```
public List<UserForm> getActiveUserList() 
{
        List<UserForm> userForms = new ArrayList<UserForm>();

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

        users = userDAO.getActiveList();

        for (User user : users) {

            String crmDomainLink=crmProperties.getProperty("CRMAppDomain");
            UserForm userForm = new UserForm(
                    user.getUserId(),user.getName(), user.getCode(),
CRMConstants.convertUSAFormatWithTime(user.getCreatedDateTime()),
 user.getIsEnabled(), null);
            userForms.add(userForm);
        }

        return userForms;
    }
```

**MyDAO.java**

```
public List<User> getActiveList() {
return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("isEnabled", 1),Restrictions.ne("userId", 1))).list();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a custom [LogoutSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html). Something like:

```java
@Component
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities()).contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");
        }
    }
}
```

Add it to security config, if XML:

```xml
<logout success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get `Authentication` object in controller by following

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(ModelMap model, Authentication authentication) {
}
```

Then you can get the roles of logged in user by calling the following method

```
authentication.getAuthorities();
```